# When to close MySQL connection using node-mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Currently using: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

I have the following code:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'me',
    password : 'secret',
    database : 'Database1'
});
app.put('/api/upload', function(req, res, next)
{
    connection.connect();
    doMultipleQueries(function(err)
    {
        connection.end();
    });          
};
```

The put request works perfectly fine, but calling it the second time, I get the following error

```
events.js:68
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit.
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/Users/anon/Desktop/project Web/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:110:16)
```

Am I supposed to leave the connection open until the server dies?

UPDATE:
When I move the `mysql.createConnection` into the put request function like so:

```
var connection = null; 
app.put('/api/upload', function(req, res, next)
{
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'me',
        password : 'secret',
        database : 'Database1'
    });
    connection.connect();
    doMultipleQueries(function(err)
    {
        connection.end();
    });          
};
```

It works fine. Does this mean `connection.end()` closes what `mysql.createConnection` created and cannot be reconnected?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[connection.end()](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#terminating-connections) does it job regardless to fatal error. If a fatal error occurs before the `COM_QUIT` packet can be sent, an `err` argument will be provided to the callback, but the connection will be terminated regardless of that.

Also check [destroy() method](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#terminating-connections). This will cause an immediate termination of the underlying socket.

You can add error handler.

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#error-handling

```
// I am Chuck Norris:
connection.on('error', function() {});
```

---

Once terminated, an existing connection object cannot be re-connected by design.

Check here. It's showing connecting back after disconnect.

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#server-disconnects

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it doesn't help me much. I actually did have code for connection.on error which displayed the error shown above. The end() properly closes the connection, but when I try to reconnect the connection, it doesn't connect.

Comment: I'm not a GitHub user so maybe you (someone) could easily tell those guys just to add a right curly brace at the end of the function passed in  "connection.on". 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I believe the proper way is to just get a connection for your app at startup, and `end()` it when your app closes.

Comment: Probably not efficient since one connection might stall during a complex query.

Comment: If you expect long queries, use a connection pool (that is the idea behind a pool, that there is already a connection, ready for use), or make sure your query is optimized properly.  node-mysql can also let you deal with disconnects and other errors.

Comment: What do you mean by long queries ? More than 10 joins ?

Comment: @G4BB3R long query => long time consuming (for example taking >100ms)

Comment: No no no. This is correct using NoSQL (e.g. Mongo), but sql connections have a limit. If your limit is 15 (10 or 15 is the default), that means you can only have 15 people on your site at any one time. You should be closing the connections after you're done doing what you need to do.

Comment: If one user need one connection all the time, then yes pool limit of 10 means maximum 10 users at one time. However when coded properly, not all pages require a database query, and once the query finished executing the connection should be released. Therefore allowing more than 10 users to browse the site at the same time.

Comment: @DavidS is right, this is a serious issue, connection needs to be closed., I have tested it with connection release and as soon as the limit of 10 exceeds application doesn't work,