# Closing Connection on SailsJS

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I'm using Sails JS with sails-mysql 0.12.1.
And I'm utilizing query() method to do query from database, but lately I'm getting Too Many Connection SQL problems.

This is my setting:

```
db: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'my db',
    user: 'my user',
    port: 3306,
    password: 'my password',
    database: 'l2alpha',
    connectionLimit: 0,
    pool: false
  },
```

Just wondering if this sails-mysql close the connection automatically after doing the query? Because I cannot find how to close the connection manually on the documentation

Comment: Better to use node-mysql or similar if you're doing direct queries, reason is flexibility. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13266313/2110294. This is what you want to do correct? Not sure that sails-mysql supports this.