# Node.js mysql stream query gets fired twice or more

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-streams

I have an application which connects to a MySQL-Database via SSH when i want to add a piece of hardware (a terminal) to my mysql database. This is the function for that:

```
    const SSHConnection = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        sshClient.on('ready', async () => {
            sshClient.forwardOut(
            forwardConfig.srcHost,
            forwardConfig.srcPort,
            forwardConfig.dstHost,
            forwardConfig.dstPort,
            (err, stream) async => {
                 if (err) reject(err);
               
                // create a new DB server object including stream
                const updatedDbServer = {
                     ...dbServer,
                     stream
                };
                // connect to mysql
                const connection = mysql.createConnection(updatedDbServer);
                // check for successful connection
               //  resolve or reject the Promise accordingly          
               connection.connect(async (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }

                let query = await connection.promise().query("INSERT INTO `mandator_1`.`terminal` (`serialNumber`, `name`, `isActive`, `status`, `profileId`, `businessId`, `divisionId`, `ipAddress`, `groupId`, `setupVersion`, `macAddress`) VALUES ('" + terminal.serial + "', '" + terminal.serial + "', '1', NULL, '1', '1', NULL, '172.45.17.197', '1', NULL, '" + terminal.macAddress + "');");
                let updateTerminal = await connection.promise().query("UPDATE `terminal` SET `status` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) * 1000,  `setupVersion` = '005', `hardwareType` = '10', `update` = 0, `lastUpdated` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) * 1000, `dataReceived` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) * 1000 WHERE `setupVersion` IS NULL AND `hardwareType` IS NULL AND `lastUpdated` IS NULL AND `dataReceived` IS NULL AND `serialNumber` = '"+ terminal.serial +"'");

                resolve(connection);
                });
           });
        }).connect(tunnelConfig);
    });
```

if i now delete the terminal, and add another one, the first terminal is added also again. I think it has sth. to do with the stream/database connection. Maybe it needs to be closed or cleared after the first terminal is added?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is not recommended to leave connections open, except for terminal-like applications.
You should make sure the connections are closed once the application closes, to prevent resource-leakage, by executing connection.end() .
Closing the connection will effectively disconnect the first terminal from the database and should fix your problem.
See link for reference:
[When to close MySQL connection using node-mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266013/when-to-close-mysql-connection-using-node-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Tabular database it's important to open and close the connection at every time you want to communicate:

```
const SSHConnection = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        sshClient.on('ready', async () => {
            sshClient.forwardOut(
            forwardConfig.srcHost,
            forwardConfig.srcPort,
            forwardConfig.dstHost,
            forwardConfig.dstPort,
            (err, stream) async => {
                 if (err) reject(err);
               
                // create a new DB server object including stream
                const updatedDbServer = {
                     ...dbServer,
                     stream
                };
                // connect to mysql
                const connection = mysql.createConnection(updatedDbServer);
                // check for successful connection
               //  resolve or reject the Promise accordingly          
               connection.connect(async (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
                let query = await connection.promise().query("INSERT INTO `mandator_1`.`terminal` (`serialNumber`, `name`, `isActive`, `status`, `profileId`, `businessId`, `divisionId`, `ipAddress`, `groupId`, `setupVersion`, `macAddress`) VALUES ('" + terminal.serial + "', '" + terminal.serial + "', '1', NULL, '1', '1', NULL, '172.45.17.197', '1', NULL, '" + terminal.macAddress + "');");
                let updateTerminal = await connection.promise().query("UPDATE `terminal` SET `status` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) * 1000,  `setupVersion` = '005', `hardwareType` = '10', `update` = 0, `lastUpdated` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) * 1000, `dataReceived` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) * 1000 WHERE `setupVersion` IS NULL AND `hardwareType` IS NULL AND `lastUpdated` IS NULL AND `dataReceived` IS NULL AND `serialNumber` = '"+ terminal.serial +"'");
                openConnection();
                resolve(connection);
                });
           });
        }).connect(tunnelConfig);
      closeConnection();
    });
openConnection(){
//Define the Connection let's say you're variable for connection is connect you can also try checks with it for error prevention 
connect.open(); 
}

closeConnection(){
//Define the Connection let's say you're variable for connection is connect
connect.close(); 
}
```